# Custom Prestashop Webservice CRUD methods

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a PS Module to insert asociated stores data (name, url, apiKey...) into a new table of another PS Store as a centralized one.

I've accomplished to create new webservice, check GET, POST and DELETE CRUD checkboxes and established Webservice Key for my custom webservice. Now I wish to record new associated store via webservice url.

What I did is that:

Override **webserviceRequest (override/clases/webservice/webserviceRequest.php)**

```
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore {
    public function __construct() {
        include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mycustomwebservicedir'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'models'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myCustomClassForWs.php');
    }

    public static function getResources()
    {
        $resources = parent::getResources();
        $resources['myCustomWs'] = array('description' => 'Description for my custom webservice', 'class' => 'myCustomClassForWs');
        ksort($resources);
        return $resources;
    }
}
```

And this is my code for my custom class (**models/myCustomClassForWs.php**)

```
class myCustomClassForWs extends ObjectModel
{
    public $store_name;
    public $store_url;
    public $store_api_key;
    public $store_contact_email;

    public static $definition = [
        'table'     => _DB_PREFIX_.'mycustomtable',
        'primary'   => 'id_primary_key',
        'fields'    => [
            'store_name'            => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true],
            'store_url'             => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true],
            'store_api_key'         => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true],
            'store_contact_email'   => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'required' => true],
        ]
    ];

    protected $webserviceParameters = [];
}
```

So, my question is, how to handle custom webservice to insert into my new table by passing params via Webservice URL.

Edit: I've added a piece of the XML Response when trying to access http://localhost/prestashop/prestashop-base/api/centralized_store

[image: Browser Webservice response]